# Get list of packages in a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, namespaces, package

I m using the below code to get the list of packages in the give java project. But it is including the folders also in the list. Please suggest a way to ignore folders.

```
final IPackageFragmentRoot[] packageFragmentRootArray = workingJavaProject.getJavaProject().getAllPackageFragmentRoots();

for (final IPackageFragmentRoot packageFragmentRoot : pkgFrgmRoots) {
        if (!packageFragmentRoot.isArchive()) {
            for (final IJavaElement pkg : packageFragmentRoot.getChildren()) {
                if (pkg != null && !isEmpty(pkg.getElementName()) && pkg instanceof IPackageFragment) {
                    allPackages.add((IPackageFragment) pkg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPackageFragment can be an instantiate of IFiles, IFolders, or IStorages. One possible solution:

```
if (pkg != null && !isEmpty(pkg.getElementName()) && pkg instanceof IPackageFragment) {
    if (!(pkg instanceof IFolder)) {
        allPackages.add((IPackageFragment) pkg);
    }
}
```